# Is it safe to wind a primary with parallel wires to increase current carrying capacity?

Tags: power, toroidal

Is it possible to increase current carrying capacity of a toroidal transformer by using two 16ga enamel wires? This is for a step-up 120-240 VAC toroidal transformer I want to wind.

Answer (score 1):

> is it safe to wind a primary with parallel wires to increase current carrying capacity? would 2x16ga have twice the current capacity in a toroid?

If you double up the wires, the primary resistance will be halved. But if you double the current at the same time, the power dissipated by the wires will be doubled.

$$P = I^2 R$$

The number of winding layers in a toroidal transform is usually very small, so heat typically escapes from the windings more freely than with a typical EI core transformer. Even so, the extra power dissipation is something to consider. If the transformer runs hot *before* modification, doubling the current will make it run hotter, and the insulation may have a reduced lifetime.

Also, consider what happens in the secondary. Regardless of how low you reduce the primary resistance, you will not get extra current unless the secondary draws extra current. You did not mention reducing the resistance of the secondary winding. If you double the current in the secondary while maintaining the same resistance, the secondary winding will produce 4 times as much heat. Again, toroidal transformers lose heat more readily than some other configurations. But the extra heat is something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

> *is it safe to wind a primary with parallel wires to increase current
> carrying capacity? would 2x16ga have twice the current capacity in a
> toroid?*

It's safe and will double the current carrying capability of your primary to do this but, make sure both windings are would in a bifilar manner to avoid tears. It can be a little bit tricky but, it's doable when the number of turns are wound in a single layer carefully or, on two layers extremely carefully.

Bifilar winding: -

[image]

[Source of image](https://e-magnetica.pl/doku.php/bifilar_winding).

<sub>Doing this does not mean that the transformer secondary has a new-found ability to deliver twice the output current.</sub>

Comment: what happens if the two wires are twisted?

Comment: Twisting wires reduces inductance even more.